# Предотвращение сложения векторов при диагональном перемещении персонажа

Tags: c#, unity3d

Написал простейший код перемещения на Unity:

```
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    playerRigidbody.AddForce(GetMovementAxis() * m_Acceleration);
}

private Vector3 GetMovementAxis()
{
    float horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float vertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    return new Vector3(horizontal, 0, vertical);
}
```

Проблема заключается в том, что при движении по диагонали векторы складываются и персонаж начинает перемещаться быстрее. Применение `Vector3.normalized` решает эту проблему, но перемещение во время ускорения/замедления начинает обрабатываться некорректно, потому что длина вектора всегда остаётся статичной.

**Поэтому возник вопрос:** Возможно ли без каких-то костылей добиться вменяемого результата, чтобы и сохранить плавность движения, и избавиться от диагонального ускорения? А может быть, проще будет использовать какой-нибудь другой способ перемещения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тупо проверить, а нужно ли нормализировать...

```
public Vector2 GetInputAxis ()
{
    Vector2 axis = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
    if (axis.magnitude > 1)
        axis.Normalize();
    return axis;
}
```